# Types for destructed function arguments in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

I can define types for destructured function arguments in TypeScript:

```
import { state, myAction } from "store/types";

type Args = {
  state: state;
  action: myAction;
};

const move = ({ state, action }: Args) => {
```

However can you specify the types inline? So something like:

```
const move = ({ state: state, actionL: actionMoveExerciseUp }) => {
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then you will need to do this:

```
const move = ({ state, action }: { state: state, action: myAction }) => {
    // More logic here
}
```

This is because your original code is actually simply [reassigning the value to another variable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Assigning_to_new_variable_names). `({ state: state, action: actionMoveExerciseUp })` means that the value of `action` will be accessible as `actionmoveExercuseUp` inside the scope of the arrow function instead of `action`.